# 3D-эффект наведения на кнопку

Tags: html, css, css-animation, css-selectors

Я пытаюсь воспроизвести этот эффект с помощью чистого CSS:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока я пробовал делать:

```css
.parent {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.hoverable-element {
        border: 0.1rem solid #000;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 1rem 2rem;

        transform: translate(0, 0);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
        
        transition: 
            box-shadow 200ms ease-out,
            transform 200ms ease-out;
}

.hoverable-element:hover {
        transform: translate(-0.5rem, -0.5rem);
        box-shadow: 
            0.1rem 0.1rem 0 #000,
            0.2rem 0.2rem 0 #000,
            0.3rem 0.3rem 0 #000,
            0.4rem 0.4rem 0 #000,
            0.5rem 0.5rem 0 #000;  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <button class="hoverable-element">Hoverable Button</button>
</div>
```

Но этот метод повторяет много ненужного кода, а также неправильно выполняет то, что я задумал. Я хочу,  чтобы «тень» кнопки `.hoverable-element` (эффект выдавливания при наведении) была окаймлена белым фоном (как показано на изображении). Кроме этого, я не знаю, с чего начать

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [3D-like hover effect on button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65374734/7394871) от участника  [@Fredrik Strøm-Larsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345367/fredrik-str%c3%b8m-larsen).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65374734/7394871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как мне кажется, логичнее было бы анимировать кнопку немного иначе. Добавить анимацию не только при наведении, но и при нажатии. Пример:

```css
button,
button:hover,
button:active {
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.parent {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.hoverable-element {
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.hoverable-element::before,
.hoverable-element::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
}

.hoverable-element::before {
  height: 1rem;
  top: 100%;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: skewX(45deg) scaleY(0.5);
}

.hoverable-element::after {
  width: 1rem;
  left: 100%;
  top: -1px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: none;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform: skewY(45deg) scaleX(0.5);
}

.hoverable-element:hover {
  transform: translate(-0.5rem, -0.5rem) scaleX(1);
}

.hoverable-element:hover::before {
  transform: skewX(45deg) scaleY(1);
}

.hoverable-element:hover::after {
  transform: skewY(45deg) scaleX(1);
}

.hoverable-element:active {
  transform: translate(0.5rem, 0.5rem) scaleX(1);
}

.hoverable-element:active::before {
  transform: skewX(45deg) scaleY(0);
}

.hoverable-element:active::after {
  transform: skewY(45deg) scaleX(0);
}

.hoverable-element>span::before {
  content: 'Кнопка';
}

.hoverable-element:active span::before {
  content: 'Кнопка нажата';
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="hoverable-element"><span></span></button>
</div>
```

Кроме этого, в соседнем ответе кнопка немного сдвигается с места при наведении. Думаю, что это небольшая ошибка. По логике такого быть не должно. Поэтому при наведении и при нажатии необходимо корректировать `transform: translate`.

**upd 1** по комментарию:

```css
button,
button:hover,
button:active {
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.parent {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.hoverable-element {
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.hoverable-element::before,
.hoverable-element::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
}

.hoverable-element::before {
  height: 1rem;
  top: 100%;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: skewX(45deg) scaleY(0.5);
}

.hoverable-element::after {
  width: 1rem;
  left: 100%;
  top: -1px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: none;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform: skewY(45deg) scaleX(0.5);
}

.hoverable-element:hover {
  transform: translate(-0.5rem, -0.5rem) scaleX(1);
}

.hoverable-element:hover::before {
  transform: skewX(45deg) scaleY(1);
}

.hoverable-element:hover::after {
  transform: skewY(45deg) scaleX(1);
}

.hoverable-element:active {
  transform: translate(0.5rem, 0.5rem) scaleX(1);
  box-shadow: none;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation: 0.07s forwards shadow 0.2s;
}

@keyframes shadow {
  from {
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: inset -1px -2px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  }
}

.hoverable-element:active::before {
  transform: skewX(45deg) scaleY(0);
}

.hoverable-element:active::after {
  transform: skewY(45deg) scaleX(0);
}

.hoverable-element>span::before {
  content: 'Кнопка';
}

.hoverable-element:active span::before {
  content: 'Кнопка нажата';
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="hoverable-element"><span></span></button>
</div>
```

**upd 2** по комментарию:

```css
button,
button:hover,
button:active {
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.parent {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.hoverable-element {
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.hoverable-element::before,
.hoverable-element::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
}

.hoverable-element::before {
  height: 1rem;
  top: 100%;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: skewX(45deg) scaleY(0.5);
}

.hoverable-element::after {
  width: 1rem;
  left: 100%;
  top: -1px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: none;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform: skewY(45deg) scaleX(0.5);
}

.hoverable-element:hover {
  transform: translate(-0.5rem, -0.5rem) scaleX(1);
}

.hoverable-element:hover::before {
  transform: skewX(45deg) scaleY(1);
}

.hoverable-element:hover::after {
  transform: skewY(45deg) scaleX(1);
}

.hoverable-element:active {
  transform: translate(0.5rem, 0.5rem) scaleX(1);
  box-shadow: none;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation: 0.05s forwards shadow 0.1s;
}

@keyframes shadow {
  from {
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
}

.hoverable-element:active::before {
  transform: skewX(45deg) scaleY(0);
}

.hoverable-element:active::after {
  transform: skewY(45deg) scaleX(0);
}

.hoverable-element>span::before {
  content: 'Кнопка';
}

.hoverable-element:active span::before {
  content: 'Кнопка нажата';
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="hoverable-element"><span></span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, так пожалуй интереснее смотрится. Но ведь можно, ещё кнопку утопить при нажатии, сделать внутренню тень.

Comment: мне кажется, что для реалистичности нужно затенять у нажатой кнопки только левый и верхний бордюры

Answer (score 4):

Вот идея с псевдоэлементом и преобразованием `skew`:

```css
.parent {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.hoverable-element {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.hoverable-element::before,
.hoverable-element::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
}

.hoverable-element::before {
  height: 1rem;
  top: 100%;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: skewX(45deg) scaleY(var(--s, 0));
}

.hoverable-element::after {
  width: 1rem;
  left: 100%;
  top: -1px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom:none;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform: skewY(45deg) scaleX(var(--s, 0));
}

.hoverable-element:hover {
  transform: translate(-0.5rem, -0.5rem);
  --s: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="hoverable-element">Hoverable Button</button>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65374846/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>